# Ongoing email alerts for content "assigned" to users via Entity Reference

Tags: rules, emails, cron, entities

I have put together a work tracking/scheduling system for the company I work for - it's built on Drupal 7 and basically enables clients, projects and tasks to be added and assigned to eachother (i.e. tasks added to projects, projects added to clients) via Entity Reference fields.

These three items are set up as Content Types, and both projects and tasks have statuses (active, ongoing, complete, etc) served by Taxonomy vocabularies. I'm also using Entity Reference to enable tasks to be "assigned" to users.

What I want to do next is set up two email alerts:

- An email alert to the user when a new task assigned to him/her has been added
- Ongoing email alerts summarising all outstanding (i.e. status not set to "complete") tasks (this would be daily, bi-daily or weekly)

I think the first is best catered for using Rules, but I'm not sure how to tackle the second. I know it depends on filtering by status and the reference field as well as being sent out at predetermined intervals, so I know it would probably involve Rules and Cron, but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Ricko, did you manage to solve this? If so, could you tell me ho? Am struggling with a similar scenario..
Thanks

Comment: @pipe_piper: unfortunately this little project has been postponed until I have time to work on it. If I make progress with it any time soon, I'll try to remember to post an update here detailing the steps I took.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://nodeone.se/en/learn-the-rules-framework
Check out episodes 2 and 3 in particular. Then watch the rest of the series. Then watch all the other series. Then rejoice that Johan Falk is so freakin' awesome.